# conditional requirement to create new column for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

```
Name   IDNum      BossNum
John   1          0
Matt   2          1
Mike   3          2
Jack   4          1
```

How can I create an additional column called BossName like below:

Expected Output:

```
Name   IDNum      BossNum     BossName
John   1          0           John/none (I don't care about boss being ided)
Matt   2          1           John
Mike   3          2           Matt
Jack   4          1           John
```

I have currently have attempted:

```
df['BossName'] = df['Name'][df['BossNum'] in df['IDNum']]
```

This didn't work at all. Any ideas as to how I can accomplish this would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a series `Name` with index as the `IDNum`, and then use `map`:

```
df['BossName'] = df.BossNum.map(df.set_index('IDNum').Name)
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Psidom already has you covered with the correct answer, but it is also worth mentioning you could explicitly create a new Series for [`map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42699618/conditional-requirement-to-create-new-column-for-pandas-dataframe/42700313#42700313) only containing what you need.

```
df.BossNum.map(pd.Series(df.Name.values, index=df.IDNum))
```

This may be slightly faster than setting the index for a small DataFrame without many columns, but will certainly be faster for a larger DataFrame with many other columns, as  you incur some additional cost as your number of columns increases when setting the index on the entire DataFrame.